# how to add or use tfx python module for catkin?

Tags: python, ros, catkin

i download a repository [ https://github.com/simon0793/pr2_simu... ] i am using catkin_workplace when ever i run python code

```
python simulation_one_motion_queue.py
```

every time error comes tfx not found as;

```
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: tfx
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/mudasser/p/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that the package `tfx` was not found. Make sure that it is on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You can try if it is already added in path by running

```
$ roscd tfx
```

that should bring you to the package directory. Otherwise you have to search and include it yourself. (Worst case, the tfx package is not installed, then you have to install it first).

Comment: can you please help me to install openravepy after tfx issue 'em facing that issue tfx issue is solved